# Advanced Filter for multiple keywords anywhere in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, advanced-filter

I'd like to advance filter a database for specific keywords in a specific column. I thought I had it worked out, but the advanced filters I was running only pulled up the rows in the database if the keywords matched the first letter of the cell, rather than anywhere in the cell. I think you'd have to use something like `<>` before the keyword to be searched, but that doesn't do anything.
Here's an example of what my data base looks like:

[image]

And I'd like to search the title column for keywords like "vice", "benefit", "medical", "Health", and "resource". If I just do an advanced filter with one of those words, it will only bring up those with a first word which matches, whereas I'd like it to bring up if those keywords appear anywhere within the Title cell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh you just put *text* asterisks around the text you want to search, not <> before.
So

```
*vice*
*health*
*medical*
```

Etc.